# passing data from screen to screen xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have this code in my ViewController1

```
var calendarios = [Calendario]()
var totalCalendarios1 = 0
```

(when the screen loads totalCalendarios change and it says the total correctly, I can see it in debug)
and I want it to pass to my ViewController2, I have made this code:

```
let copiaCalendarios = ViewController1()
let totalCalendarios2 = copiaCalendarios.totalCalendarios1
```

I printed this second value and it says 0, always, it doesn't matter that before.

I have used this code too:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destino = segue.destination as? ViewController
        destino?.calendariosCopia = calendarios
    }
```

but doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?
Have searched for info but it's outdated

EDIT:
Here it is my original code:
CalendarioViewController is my 2nd VC, and CalendarioTableViewController is my 1st VC and is the sender.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destino = segue.destination as? CalendarioViewController
        destino?.calendariosCopia = calendarios
    }
```

This is the code I have use, and this one too:

```
let copiaCalendarios = CalendarioTableViewController()
let totalCalendarios = copiaCalendarios.totalCalendarios
```

in both VC have a `var totalCalendarios = 0`

Thx ind advance and sorry for my bad English :$

EDIT2:
Does it matter the kind of segue?
Because I used 'Present Modally'

Edit3:
CalendarioTableViewController:

```
//
//  CalendarioTableViewController.swift
//  Vizion5
//
//  Created by ROB on 16/04/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 ROB. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CalendarioTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var calendarios = [Calendario]()
    var totalCalendarios = 0

    func cargarEjemplos() {

        guard let calendario1 = Calendario(nombre: "2017-A", fin: "17/01/2017", inicio: "05/05/2017") else {
            fatalError("Error en calendario table view controller")
        }

        guard let calendario2 = Calendario(nombre: "2016-A", fin: "17/01/2016", inicio: "05/05/2016") else {
            fatalError("Error en calendario table view controller")
        }

        calendarios += [calendario1, calendario2]

    }

    func contarCalendarios() {
        totalCalendarios = calendarios.count
    }

    //AÑADIDO AUTOMATICAMENTE

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //CARGA LOS EJEMPLOS
        cargarEjemplos()
        contarCalendarios()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return calendarios.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let identificadorCelda = "tablaCalendario"
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tablaCalendario", for: indexPath) as? CalendarioTableViewCell
            else {
                fatalError("error 1: calendario table controller")
        }

        let calendario = calendarios[indexPath.row]

        // Configure the cell...

        cell.nombreCalendario.text = calendario.nombre
        cell.finCalendario.text = calendario.fin
        cell.inicioCalendario.text = calendario.inicio

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: ACCIONES
    @IBAction func regresarATablaCalendario(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let viewControllerOrigen = sender.source as? CalendarioViewController, let calendario = viewControllerOrigen.calendario {
            //AÑADE EL NUEVO CALENDARIO
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: calendarios.count, section: 0)
            calendarios.append(calendario)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("Total calendarios es: " + String(totalCalendarios))
        let destino = segue.destination as? CalendarioViewController // here you have to use the exact name of your Second View Controller instead of ViewController
        destino?.totalCalendarios = totalCalendarios
    }

}
```

My CalendarioViewController

```
//
//  CalendarioViewController.swift
//  Vizion5
//
//  Created by ROB on 16/04/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 ROB. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CalendarioViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var nombreCalendario: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fechaInicioCalendario: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var fechaFinCalendario: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var botonGuardar: UIBarButtonItem!

    var totalCalendarios = 0

    //ESTE VALOR SERA PASADO POR 'CALENDARIOVIEWCONTROLLER' EN 'PREPARE(FOR: SENDER:)' O CONTRUIDO PARA AGREGAR UN NUEVO CALENDARIO
    var calendario: Calendario?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        nombreCalendario.delegate = self //SE CONTROLA A SI MISMO

        print("Total segue: " + String(totalCalendarios))

        //CHECA SI SE PUEDE HABILITAR EL BOTON DE GAURDADO
        //DESABILITA EL BOTON DE GUARDADO
        botonGuardar.isEnabled = false
        //actualizaEstadoBotonGuardar()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: FUNCIONES DE TECLADO Y DETERMINAR FECHA (QUE EL FIN SEA MAYOR QUE INICIO)

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        botonGuardar.isEnabled = false
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //SE DESHABILITA EL BOTON DE GUARDAR CUANDO SE ESCRIBE
        botonGuardar.isEnabled = false
        //ESCONDE EL TECLADO AL PRESIONADO "HECHO" (DONE)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        actualizaEstadoBotonGuardar()
        //navigationItem.title = textField.text
    }


    // MARK: - NAVEGACION (UNWIND SEGUE)
    @IBAction func botonCancelar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        //super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === botonGuardar else {
            print("Error en prepare sender")
            return
        }

        let setFormatoFecha = DateFormatter()
        setFormatoFecha.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

        let nombre = nombreCalendario.text
        let fin = setFormatoFecha.string(from: fechaFinCalendario.date)
        let inicio = setFormatoFecha.string(from: fechaInicioCalendario.date)

        //SE INSERTAN LOS DATOS LEIDOS.
        calendario = Calendario(nombre: nombre!, fin: fin, inicio: inicio)

        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }

    //MARK: METODOS PRIVADOS

    private func actualizaEstadoBotonGuardar() {
        //DESHABILITA EL BOTON DE GUARDAR CUANDO ESTA EN BLANCO *WIP*
        let texto = nombreCalendario.text ?? ""
        let tieneTexto = !texto.isEmpty

        //WIP
        if (!texto.isEmpty) {
            if (fechaInicioCalendario.date >= fechaFinCalendario.date) {
                botonGuardar.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                botonGuardar.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to have a typo. `ViewController` instead of `ViewController1`.

Comment: Do you want to pass the `[Calendario]` object or only the `totalCalendarios` var??

Comment: only totalCalendarios

Comment: @MartinHernandezPerez see my edit below.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know where I'm wrong, your code is a bit confusing to me. (I'll edit.)

Your `totalCalendarios1` is a value in an instance of `ViewController1`. It appears to me that you wish to pass this value to `ViewController2`, and into a variable called `totalCalendarios2`.

First off, you have a (small) mistake in:

```
let totalCalendarios2 = copiaCalendarios.totalCalendarios
```

Shouldn't that be `totalCalendarios1`? (This is where I get confused with your naming conventions. Hopefully this is either a language issue or you simplified your code to a point of making a typo.)

Anyways, that is a small issue. The **real** issue is with your segue code. That's where you'll correct things.

---

Let's say you have the following:

**ViewController1:**

```
var totalCalendarios:Int = 0
```

**ViewController2**

```
var totalCalendarios:Int = 0
```

Now in `ViewController1` this variable is updated to a different value, maybe 2017, and you wish to pass this value to ViewController2. All you need - provided you have a segue defined - is:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MySegueName" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            vc.totalCalendarios = totalCalendarios
        }
    }
}
```

Compared to the code posted, the largest error is casting your destination VC as `ViewController` instead of `ViewController2`. I see other potential issues, but your variables don't match up enough for me to know if they are a problem too.

To conclude:

- Unless you simply cannot keep the variable names the same, there's no issue in naming things the same between view controllers. In fact, it helps others understand your code.
- If you are using a segue, there's no need to instantiate any view controllers. But you should **cast** the destination VC properly in *prepare(for segue:)*.
- After the cast, simply pass the variable.

Comment: yes, i had corrected the code, it was totalCalendarios1, Sorry, I'll try your code, thx :D

Answer (score 0):

I assume your class name is `ViewController1` as you said. That's fine. But how did you get past `let totalCalendarios2 = copiaCalendarios.totalCalendarios`? Is it a typo or you actually wrote this line in your code? It should be:

```
let totalCalendarios2 = copiaCalendarios.totalCalendarios1
```

Well if you actually want to pass data from one screen to another screen (actually it's one controller to another controller) follow:

1. In your First View Controller (From where you want to pass), have a property of the type of data that you want to pass. For your case:

   ```
   var totalCalendarios = 0
   ```

   Now update this `totalCalendarios` according to your needs.
2. For passing data with `segue`, you need to add a segue in ***Interface Builder*** (from source controller to destination controller) and give that `segue` a name. Let's say **`CalenderSegue`**
3. In your Second View Controller (To where you want to pass), you need to have a property of the exact type of the data that you were passing from the First one. In your case it's `Int`. So declare a property in your Second View Controller:

   ```
   var totalCalendarios = 0
   ```
4. Now use this

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if let identifier = segue.identifier, identifier = "CalenderSegue" { 
           let destino = segue.destination as? CalendarioViewController // here you have to use the exact name of your Second View Controller instead of ViewController
           destino?.totalCalendarios = totalCalendarios
       }
   }
   ```

**EDIT:1**

Delete these lines from your `CalendarioViewController` class (You don't need to create object for your `CalendarioTableViewController`)

```
let copiaCalendarios = CalendarioTableViewController()
let totalCalendarios = copiaCalendarios.totalCalendarios
```

Add this to `CalendarioViewController` class

```
var totalCalendarios = 0
```

And use the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method from above.

> But if you only have one segue and you have added it from
>   `TableViewCell` to `CalendarioViewController` then you can use

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
    let destino = segue.destination as? CalendarioViewController // here you have to use the exact name of your Second View Controller instead of ViewController
    destino?.totalCalendarios = totalCalendarios
}
```

**EDIT:2**

You might have issues with the `segue`. Delete all the `segue`s from your `TableViewCell` and then add them back. If you don't know how to do, see this [image]

Comment: yes, i had corrected the code, it was totalCalendarios1, Sorry, I'll try your code, thx :D

Comment: I added a print statement in the segue piece of code, it print the var totalCalendarios, and it show 2 (total calendars loaded), then in viewDidLoad() of CalendarioViewController Printed the totalCalendarios and it says 0. This is the result:
Total Calendarios (segue): 2
Total Calendarios (CalendarioViewController): 0

Comment: @MartinHernandezPerez did you use exactly `destino?.totalCalendarios = totalCalendarios` inside your `prepare(for:sender:)` method??

Comment: Yes. I did use thos exact code: `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("Total calendarios es: " + String(calendarios.count))
        let destino = segue.destination as? CalendarioViewController // here you have to use the exact name of your Second View Controller instead of ViewController
        destino?.totalCalendarios = totalCalendarios
    }`

Comment: The problem is you printed `calendarios.count` inside this method. But you are sending `totalCalendarios` var. Try printing `totalCalendarios` here.

Comment: Or, if you just want to pass `calendarios.count` to your destination, then use this: `destino?.totalCalendarios = calendarios.count`

Comment: sorry, calendarios.count and totalCalendarios are the same. Setting totalCalendarios to print is the same, print 2 ans then 0.

Comment: Then you might have problems somewhere else. Not with passing data. Can you post code of your whole `CalendarioTableViewController ` and `CalendarioViewController ` classes?

Comment: Sure, in a moment

Comment: Done, hopefully you can understand :$